# MongoDB embedded vs reference schema for large data documents

Tags: performance, mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I am designing my first MongoDB database schema for log managment system and I would like to store information from log file to mongoDB and I can't decide what schema should I 
use for large documents (embedded vs reference).

Note: project has many sources and source has many logs (in some cases over 1 000 000 logs)

```
  {    
      "_id" : ObjectId("5141e051e2f56cbb680b77f9"),   
      "name" : "projectName",
      "source" : [{
          "name" : "sourceName",
          "log" : [{
              "time" : ISODate("2012-07-20T13:15:37Z"),
              "host" : "127.0.0.1",
              "status" : 200.0,
              "level" : "INFO",
              "message" : "test"
            }, {
              "time" : ISODate("2012-07-20T13:15:37Z"),
              "host" : "127.0.0.1",
              "status" : 200.0,
              "level" : "ERROR",
              "message" : "test"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

My focuse is on performance during the reading data from database (NOT WRITING) e.g. Filtering, Searching, Pagination etc. User can filter source log by date, status etc (so I want to focus on reading performance when user search or filtering data)

I know that MongoDB has a 16Mbyte document size limit so I am worried if I gonna have 1 000 000 logs for one source how this gonna work (as I can have many sources for one project and sources can have many logs). What is better solutions when I gonna work with large documents and I want to have good reading performance, should I use embedded or reference schema? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is neither.  Instead of embedding or using references, you should flatten the schema to one doc per log entry so that it scales beyond whatever can fit in the 16MB doc limit and so that you have access to the full power and performance of MongoDB's querying capabilities.

So get rid of the array fields and move everything up to top-level fields using an approach like:

```js
{    
    "_id" : ObjectId("5141e051e2f56cbb680b77f9"),   
    "name" : "projectName",
    "sourcename" : "sourceName",
    "time" : ISODate("2012-07-20T13:15:37Z"),
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "status" : 200.0,
    "level" : "INFO",
    "message" : "test"
  }, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5141e051e2f56cbb680b77fa"),   
    "name" : "projectName",
    "sourcename" : "sourceName",
    "time" : ISODate("2012-07-20T13:15:37Z"),
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "status" : 200.0,
    "level" : "ERROR",
    "message" : "test"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think having logs in an array might get messy..If project and source entities don't have any attributes(keys) other than a name and logs are not to be stored for long, you may use a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) having one log per document:

`{_id: ObjectId("5141e051e2f56cbb680b77f9"),
p: "project_name",
s: "source_name",
"time" : ISODate("2012-07-20T13:15:37Z"),
"host" : "127.0.0.1",
"status" : 200.0,
 "level" : "INFO",
"message" : "test"}`

Refer this as well: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-log-data/

Capped collections maintain natural order. So you don't need an index on timestamp to return the logs in natural order. In your case, you may want to retrieve all logs from a particular source/project. You can create index`{p:1,s:1}`to speed up this query.

But I'd recommend you do some 'benchmarking' to check performance. Try the capped collection approach above. And also try *bucketing* of documents with the fully embedded schema that you have suggested. This technique is used in the classic [blog-comments](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/) problem. Hence you only store so many logs of each source inside a single document and overflow to a new document whenever the custom-defined size exceeds.